# php array_push not pushing

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html form, that has in `input type="number"`, and using javascript, sets the amount of `input`s in a div, each one with a unique name: `item1`, `item2`...

I am currently trying to set the values of the inputs in one php array, and then loop through to get the contents, however the `echo $item` doesn't print anything.

```
$items = array();
if (isset($_POST['num'])) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= intval($_POST['num']); $i++) {
        array_push($items, $_POST['item' + $i]);
    }
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

If it helps, here is my html form and javascript:

```
How many Items: <input min="1" max="5" type="number" onchange="updateInput(this.value, document.getElementById('itemSpace'), 1, 5)" name="num"/>
Enter the items: <div id="itemSpace" name="itemSpace"></div>
```

Js:

```
function updateInput(value, elem, min, max) {
    if (value > min - 1 && value < max + 1) {
        if (value < elem.childElementCount) {
            var oldVal = (value - elem.childElementCount) * -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < oldVal; i++) {
                elem.removeChild(elem.childNodes[elem.childElementCount - 1]);
            }
        } else {
            var children = elem.childElementCount
            var newVal = value; - elem.childElementCount;
            for (var j = 0; j < newVal; j++) {
                var newElem = document.createElement("input");
                newElem.setAttribute("type", "text");
                newElem.setAttribute("name", "item" + (children - j + 1));                          elem.appendChild(newElem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what value is $_POST['num']?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `print_r($_POST)` here?

Comment: gets the input field with the name num

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` outputs Array ( [player-num] => 1 )

Comment: So we got your problem. There is no num index. Only the player-num index. Change the num index into player-num und your code should work like a charme.

Comment: if that is the output of `print_r($_POST)` then this will fail `if (isset($_POST['num'])) {` since there is no `num` index in your POST

Comment: @Marcel It will still fail because of this `$_POST['item' + $i])`

Comment: Yep ... absolutely right @hungrykoala

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
if (isset($_POST['num'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['num'] as $key => $num) {
    $items[] = $_POST['item' + $key]
  }
}
```

If $_POST['num'] is set, a foreach gets called where you can convert this to $key => $value, so you get the $key which you can use later.

Is there a reason why you use `array_push`? If you just want to add an element to an array, you could also type $arrayName[] = '...'.

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['num']`.. wont work because foreach takes in an array, not a number